# Shortest code for infinite disk I/O

Tags: code-golf

(Just open 50 tabs in Google Chrome :D (just kidding, no you can't))

Shortest code for infinite disk I/O any language, C# example:

```cs
using System.IO;

namespace FileApp {
    static class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            do {
                File.WriteAllText("a", "a");
                File.Delete("a");
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't just fill the entire disk though, as then it would halt in the end and would be finite.

And you can't do reading only, infinite writing has to happen. (It has to kill my SSD after enough runtime.)

Get cracking! :)

Comment: Does *reading* files instead of writing them also count as disk I/O? What about writing to `/dev/null`? (Is `yes>/dev/null` a valid Bash answer?)

Comment: Good point, I changed the question to require infinite writing.

Comment: Can it take any input ?

Comment: Sure, as long as it is not infinite user input.

Comment: This is heavily biased towards shell scripts, but such is life.

Comment: Dang man...what did your SSD do to you?

Comment: Would this kill the ssd though? Wouldn't the writes get cached (kernel or disk cache) and then removed again before hitting the nand chips?

Comment: As I can't hope to compete with 6 byte solutions, would creating the file ./a with the 3 byte contents ./a count for a bonus prize for lateral thinking? AFAIK just executing a file causes *some* file system writing to take place on many systems, because at the very least 'last access time' gets updated as a byproduct ;-)

Comment: Can't stay. Giving talk. Oh no, they switched to my screen...where is it...ah, there! Bye!

Comment: (Note: I actually showed that during the talk a couple of minutes ago.)

Comment: Many of these answers will write the data into the same space over and over.  That does not result in an actual disk write even if the data differs.  (Extreme case, dos -> windows communications.  I wrote 4k of data in dos and read it back in Windows--so long as data was flowing the disk light would stay off.)

Comment: Does "infinite" here mean "until an error occurs" (e.g. disk full), or literally infinite?  If you write sequentially until the disk is full, are you allowed to quit, or do you have to start over?

Comment: Literally infinite, the disk cannot be full.

Comment: @Doorknob `/dev/null` is provided by Linux/Mac/whatever kernel, it isn't on the disk (or at least will not affect the disk when written to).

Comment: `um...what?` Infinite disk I/O is a sure way of sentencing your SSD to death.

Comment: I was referring to CatsAreFluffy ;)

Comment: @Stilez: A program that just `exec`'s itself repeatedly, to create access-time metadata I/O on file holding the script?  That will work as well as most answers on systems that don't use the default lazy `relatime` or `noatime` mount options.  However, 3 bytes won't do it: you'll run out of PIDs.  (Some of the script answers have the same problem.  Programs with resource leaks aren't going to be able to wear out an SSD before crashing).

Comment: Does it need to be disk I/O, or will tape I/O work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### DOS/Batch: 4 bytes

```
%0>x
```

This batch file will call itself (`%0`) and redirect (`>`) the output to a file called `x`. Since echo is on by default, this will output the path and command.

Comment: Will this run out of disk space eventually, or is the output overwritten?

Comment: @MathuSumMut: With `>` it will be overwritten. `>>` would append

Comment: You win then I guess :P

Comment: Why can't echo be off before running this? (I've seen many answers like this)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: if echo is off, only explicit output is shown on the console. Things like commands and even the prompt will disappear. `%0` is the only thing that could generate output, but it doesn't do that on its own, it needs the shell to output a copy of the command implicitly.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I mean someone might have turned off echo before running this code.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: That's true. In that case, a file with 0 byte is produced, not generating I/O as expected by this challenge. But it's not our task to consider every case, otherwise you might want to turn off caching, virus scanners, ...

Comment: Writing a 0 byte file will still cause disk I/O, as it has to update the last-modified time within the directory.

Answer (score 48):

### PowerShell v2+, 10 bytes

```
for(){1>1}
```

Simply loops infinitely with an empty `for` loop. Each iteration, we output the integer `1` (implicitly converted to a string) with the `>` [redirect operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx), which overwrites the file named `1` in the local directory.

Comment: Could you replace the second 1 with anything else (that makes a valid file name) or does it have to be 1?

Comment: On my Windows VM, `Winload.exe` is sufficient...

Comment: I think it has to be a number because if it is a letter then it would be treated as a variable, to treat it as a string quotes are required, and they waste bytes. :P

Comment: @QPaysTaxes MathuSum has it correct. The second `1` needs to be a number of some sort in order for the implicit parsing to work correctly. Anything from `[0-9]` would work the same.

Comment: Love seeing a PowerShell answer score so high! However I don't understand your statements about the second 1 needing to be a number - it seems to work fine for me with `a` instead, and i dont see why powershell would parse it as anything other than the string `a`

Comment: @Nacht Maybe it's a quirk of my particular environment, then. In my ISE (PSv4 Win8.1), replacing the second `1` with anything non-numeric (and not specified either as `.\a` or `a.txt` or the like) results in a parse error.

Comment: @Nacht OK, now I'm definitely convinced it's a bug in my particular environment, since `for(;;){1>a}` works fine.

Answer (score 27):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
#.w]]0
```

Pyth's only file output command is `.w`. When called on a string, it writes that string to a file in append mode, which is no good for the purpose of this question. When called on a 2-d array, it writes the corresponding image to that file, overwriting the file contents. That's what this program does. The default file output name is `o.png`, so this program infinitely overwrites the file `o.png` with a 1-pixel white image. `#` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 26):

If you want a shorter (but more boring than my other one) answer:

## Bash, 5 bytes

```
>w;$0
```

I could make that shorter if there's a command (less than 3 bytes long) that writes something to disk I/O.  Something like `sync` would work, but `sync` is 4 bytes

Note: this doesn't work when run straight from bash, only when put in a script and run as the script name. (i.e. `echo 'w>w;$0' > bomb; chmod 755 bomb; ./bomb`)

Comment: Looks like it's a tie between me and @isaacg - who wins?

Comment: I prefer using `exec` (or `. $0`). I think this will run out of PIDs.

Comment: Is the first `w` needed here? For me simply `>w` creates an empty file `w`, and doing that in a loop will create infinite I/O because the mtime metadata needs to be updated continually.

Comment: If that qualifies @HenningMakholm then I'll put it in.

Comment: hmm...I think it qualifies as good rule circumventing, although the winner was already announced, but you can still post it if you like. :)

Comment: @MathuSumMut I made an edit.  Personally I feel that mine should be counted simply as the bash code itself for the bytecount.  Every other entry here must be executed as a script in a file, so how is mine different?

Comment: Alright bro, enjoy

Comment: If it only works if put into a script, than the script should also be taken into consideration when calculating the size. Just when I access external resources, it also adds to the code size.

Comment: The script only contains these bytes.  Since it's bash there's no compiler or anything fancy needed.

Answer (score 16):

### Ruby, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
loop{open(?a,?w)<<1}
```

Repeatedly truncates and writes a `1` to the file `a`.

Thanks to [Ventero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84/ventero) for 2 bytes!

Comment: `open(?a,?w)<<1` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, doorknob, for honouring us with your presence. I am humbled.

Comment: Does that leak file descriptors?  Or does it get closed when it goes out of scope?  (IDK Ruby, sorry).

Answer (score 13):

## cmd, 14 bytes

```
:a
cd>1
goto a
```

Infinitly overwrites the file `1` with the string to the current directory

---

I'm new here:
Are *windows* new lines (`CR` `LF`) counted as two bytes?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Windows, at least modern systems, should be able to handle just `LF` without issue. The above works for me with just `LF` on Windows 8.1, so your 14 bytes is correct.

Comment: `CR` `LF`2`CR`1`LF`1

Answer (score 13):

## Bash + coreutils, 10

```bash
yes \>b|sh
```

Writes a continuous stream of `>b`, which is piped to `sh` for evaluation.  `>b` simply truncates a file called `b` to zero bytes each time.

Comment: +1 because your name is really appropriate to what this snippet of code will do

Comment: Why `b` and not `c`?

Answer (score 9):

## Perl 5, <s>27</s> <s>32</s> 22 bytes

```
{{open my$h,'>o'}redo}
```

If simply changing the modification timestamp of a file suffices...

Quick explanation:

```
{ # Braces implicitly create/mark a loop.
    { # They also create closures, for `my` variables.
        open my $filehandle, '>', 'o';    # Writing to file "o".
        # close $filehandle;   # Called implicitly when
                               # variable gets destroyed.
    } # $filehandle gets destroyed because there are no references to it.
    redo; # ...the loop.
}
```

---

Previous solution (32 bytes): `{{open my$h,'>o';print$h 1}redo}`

**Edit:** `{open F,'O';print F 1;redo}` ← Didn't test the code before posting; now I had to correct it.

Comment: :o a perl variable not prefixed with `$`!

Comment: @cat: It's not a regular variable, like a scalar, array, or hash. It is simply a bareword. Depending on context, a bareword can be taken as a sub (a function), a glob, I think, or a filehandle. (Maybe others too?)

Answer (score 8):

### PHP, <s>60 30 17 16</s> 15 bytes

Updated yet again as per @manatwork suggested:

```
while(!`cd>1`);
```

Also now tested.

---

A bit of cheating 22 bytes:

<s>while(exec('>1 dir'));</s>

Earlier suggestion by @manatwork 30 bytes:

<s>while(file_put_contents(1,1));</s>

NOT TESTED (no php available on this computer) 43 bytes:

<s>for($a=fopen(1,'w');fputs($a,1);fclose($a))</s>

A golfed original 45 bytes:

<s>$a=fopen(1,'w');while(fputs($a,1))rewind($a);</s>

My first post here, joined because I just had to try this out: as long as file write succeeds, rewind file pointer to start.

---

<s>Just can't get smaller than the file_put_contents().</s>

Comment: `while(file_put_contents(1,1));` should be enough. Note that running full scripts from command line as `php -r '…'` is acceptable as per consensus on meta [Running PHP with `-r` instead of code tags](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/running-php-with-r-instead-of-code-tags).

Comment: Is this actually writing to disk or just a buffer in memory?

Comment: @manatwork Oh man! I knew there's always room for improvement, but that much... too bad that function hasn't got shorter name. :D I don't know about the buffer.. I wonder if I should update the answer with that shorter solution.

Comment: If it's shorter, please do update your answer, go ahead! :)

Comment: Is it allowed to call exec() from php? I realize it is no more in php's "scope".

Comment: Yes, executing external commands is allowed by default. Sadly your `while(exec('>1 dir'));` idea will not work as is: `exec()`'s return value is the last line from the executed command's stdout. As you are redirecting the execute command's output to a file, nothing will reach stdout, so `exec()` will return empty string. Which being falsy value in PHP, the `while` will immediately terminate. Fortunately negating the condition is quite short. By the way, better use the [Execution Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) instead of `exec()`: `while(!\`>1 dir\`);`.

Comment: That's just wrong, having such shorthands in php.. nice solution though.

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>95</s> <s>94</s> <s>93</s> <s>89</s> <s>78</s> <s>90</s> <s>89</s> <s>76</s> 75 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(){for(FILE*f=fopen("a","w");;fputc(0,f),fclose(f));}
```

Again, `` sudo watch -n1 lsof -p `pidof inf` ``  seems to say this is valid.

<sup>HOW DID I NOT SEE THAT SPACE D:<</sup>

Thanks [@Jens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9533/jens) for shaving off 13 bytes :D

Comment: The `w+` mode is read and write, initially truncating the file. Since you don't need to read, you can shave off a byte with just `w`, which also truncates the file, but doesn't open the file in read mode.

Comment: No need for `return 0;` if the loop never terminates.

Comment: Why not use `fputc(1,f)` instead of the super-verbose `fprintf(f," ")`?

Comment: `main(){for(FILE*f=fopen("a","w");;fputc(1,f),fclose(f));}` since an empty conditional in `for` means `true`. 76 bytes.

Comment: @Jens because of course I didn't know about `fputc`. Now I do :D

Comment: You don't need the `fputc` at all.  fopen/fclose will cause disk I/O for the metadata.  Also, you appear to have two `;;` back to back.  Also, @Jens: you never need `return 0` in main: the C standard specifies an implicit `return 0` at the end of `main`.  Even if not, you'd just return whatever happened to be left in the return-value register, which is fine.  Outside of golfing, you should of course `return 0` explicitly at the end of `main`, and use its proper function signature!

Comment: Also, you don't need `sudo` for `lsof` to work on your own processes.

Comment: @PeterCordes The two `;;` are in `for(;;)` and on purpose as explained. They are required.

Comment: @Jens: oh, I didn't notice that was inside the `for()` condition, rather than the body.  That means the `fopen()` only happens once, so all but the first iteration is operating on a closed `FILE*`.  It crashes on Linux (double-`free` detected on the `fclose` of the already-closed `FILE*`), and there's no way it can possibly do what we need on any system, because we need `fopen` to run repeatedly to truncate.

Comment: @Jens: here's a working version that's the same length, taking advantage of the required `;`s in the `for` structure: `main(){for(FILE*f;f=fopen("a","w");fclose(f))fputc(0,f);}`.  I actually tested it, and it runs, actually producing disk activity on Linux.  (Also see my C and C++ answers, though.)

Comment: I incorporated that into my own answer, with improvements.  (e.g. don't include `stdio.h`)

Comment: I [left an edit which fixed the bug and added an ungolfed version](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30453), but reviewers rejected it with a claim that it "deviates from the original intent".  I thought it might be rejected, but not with that reason.  Oh well, I give up on trying to save time for future readers seeing this version.

Comment: @PeterCordes PPCG is not Stack Overflow; please do not make edits to others' answers which change code or other major parts of the answer. Typo fixes are fine, but anything beyod that (including corrections of factually incorrect statements) should be suggested in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the clue on etiquette on this site.  I had hoped that adding explanations / ungolfed versions would be appreciated :/.  Any idea how that reject reason makes sense, though?  Obviously the "original intent" wasn't to be wrong.  Or is this a common thing on PPCG, where none of the canned responses are "too big a change", so you just use that?  I expected that if it was rejected, it would be for "too big", or "self promotion".

Comment: @PeterCordes Well, on most SE sites, collaboration and editing is welcomed but on PPCG, which is *unique*, a users' answer is sorta sacred and by changing their code or making other large changes, you do "deviate from the original intent of the author" (whereas this is typically fine on SO, etc). Also, the "canned-response-is-wrong-or-slightly-off" phenomena is in fact SE-wide, and Mother Meta gets many many posts about it. :)

Comment: @PeterCordes If you have any questions about this or PPCG in general, you can always come say hi [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240) or post on [meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39782/discussion-between-cat-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 7):

## sh, 11 bytes

```
w>w;exec $0
```

Save this to a file without special characters, such as loop.sh, make it executable, and run it with `./loop.sh` or similar.

This writes the output of the command `w` to the file `w`, overwriting the previous value each time. Then, it replaces itself with a fresh version of the same program, so it can run infinitely.

Comment: this is missing a second `>`. also, assuming you have a "special" `$PATH` and "special" umask/filesystem, you can go for `w>>w;$0`, brining it down to 7 chars

Comment: @mnagel `>>` is append, it will eventually fill the disk

Comment: @mnagel but you're right about not needing exec,I didn't realize that. Someone else has done it, so I won't update, though

Comment: Or `. $0` instead of `exec $0`, perhaps? I don't know if that will run cause a stack overflow or something, though. ... Yep, it segfaulted.

Answer (score 6):

## CPython 3.5, <s>33</s> 16 bytes

```
while 1:open("a")
```

Yes, really. :D

Comment: `while 1:open("a","w")` is shorter and `strace` shows that python is doing open, fstat64 and close, definitely I/O operations. If the file `a` already exists, it can be even shorter: `while 1:open('a')` which still generates an `open`, `fstat64` and `close`, and even modifies `atime` of the file.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík :0 Thank you, I didn't know that handy piece of information! Of course, it's implementation specific.

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, 26 bytes

```
yes>y&while :;do rm y;done
```

If I were to expand this one-liner, I would get this:

```
yes > y &      # Write out infinitely to the file y in the current directory
while true     # Let's do something forever
do             # Here's what we're going to do
    rm y       # delete y
done           # That's all we're going to do
```

This can't exactly compete with the 10 byte PowerShell line, but it'll hold its own against the others.  See my other answer for the 6 byte version.

Comment: `while :;ls>l;done`

Comment: The good old [`exec` trick](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=bash+%22exec+%240%22) will do better: `ls>l;exec $0`. Shorter, but boring.

Comment: `:>l;exec $0` - file creation is writing the inode

Comment: Also if you don't have the 'l' alias, you could use 'w'

Comment: @manatwork That will run out of disk space, will it not?

Comment: @Daniel No, `>` overwrites.

Comment: Ah, my bad \*facepalm\*

Comment: Even though you delete `y`, `yes` will still continue to write to the same file handle that it had. Run `lsof | grep yes` and you should see something like `/path/to/y (deleted)`.  This will fill up the disk and fail.

Comment: Instead of `rm y` you can use `>y` which will truncate the existing file. It is also a bit shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC, 12 bytes

```
While 1
Archive A
UnArchive A
End
```

Alternate solution by user [lirtosiast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/lirtosiast) with the same size:

```
While 1
SetUpEditor
Archive ∟1
End
```

This will work on the TI-83+ and TI-84+ series of calculators.

*Yes, this also works if A is already archived or is not initialized at all at the start of the program! The program is only 12 bytes because of [tokenization](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4764/52694)*.

Comment: I don't know if the flash memory used by the calculators counts as "disk".

Comment: @lirtosiast In Jamy's defense, SSDs are made of flash memory =)

Comment: In any case, the byte count is at least 10 bytes less. The 2nd Mem screen counts a header equal to 9 bytes + the length of the program name, but we don't here so you can subtract it out.

Comment: @lirtosiast This repeatedly writes and reads to the ROM (permanent memory) of the calculator, not the RAM. Of course, calculators don't have an actual hard drive inside :)

Comment: @lirtosiast Thanks, I didn't know about that! (I was wondering why the amount of bytes my TI-84+ reported didn't match up with my hand-counting...) I've updated my answer.

Comment: I couldn't find anything shorter, but `SetUpEditor:Archive L1` is the same size.

Comment: @lirtosiast Added your solution to my answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 10 bytes

```
`1[]T3$Z#T
```

#### Explanation

This is an infinite loop that writes number `1`  to a file called `inout` in current directory, overwriting previous file's contents.

```
`       % do...while loop
  1     %   push number 1
  []    %   push empty array
  T     %   push "true"
  3$Z#  %   fwrite function. First input is file content. Second is file name;
        %   defaults to "inout" if empty. Third indicates that any previous
        %   file contents should be discarded
  T     %   push "true": loop condition 
        % implicitly end loop. Loop condition is "true", so the loop is infinite
```

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 20 bytes

```
f=writeFile"b""a">>f
```

Write the string `"a"` to a file named `"b"` and repeat. `writeFile` overwrites the file if it exists.

Answer (score 4):

## ZSH, 14 bytes

```
for ((;;)) :>:
```

Zsh, unlike Bash and other Bourne-like shells, allows [loops without the `do ... done` fence](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands-1), provided the condition is suitably delimited.

Alternatively, with `while`:

```
while {} {:>:}
```

Note that `:` is a builtin. **You can't suspend this loop.**

The principle is the same as in [Digital Trauma's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76831/31018) - nothing is written to the file, the IO is purely from creating and truncating the file.

Comment: I gotta say, I never thought I'd see muru, *the* muru, come play Code Golf. Welcome to PPCG :D

Comment: @cat Thanks. :D I have played once before.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (Node.js), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
(c=x=>require("fs").writeFile("a",x,c))()
```

Writes `null` to a file named `a`, then repeat.

Comment: What about writing `c` or `x` to the file? Saves 2 bytes. Also, doesn't `require\`fs\`` work?

Comment: @Charlie Good point with writing `c` or `x`. `require\`fs\`` unfortunately doesn't work, because using backticks to call a function calls it with the first arguments as `["fs"]` (array, which first and only element is the passed string) instead of `"fs"` (just the string). Try `console.log\`test\`` for example.

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, 84 Bytes

```rust
fn main(){loop{use std::io::Write;std::fs::File::create("a").unwrap().write(b"a");}}
```

`File::create` truncates an existing file, thus ensuring that we don't run out of disk space.

The used Compiler (1.9 Nightly) issues a warning about the unused result of `write(...)` but compiles nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 92 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){for(FILE*f=fopen("a","w+");fprintf(f," "),!fclose(f);;);return 0;}
```

While it looks like you could save 1 byte by

```
  for(FILE*f=fopen("a","w+");fprintf(f," ")+fclose(f);;){}
```

the problem with that loop is that + doesn't give you the guaranteed order.

Or recursive - shouldn't overflow if the compiler properly implements tail recursion (f is in an explicit inner scope)

## 85 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){{FILE*f=fopen("a","w+");fprintf(f," ");fclose(f);}main();}
```

Comment: Hopefully the 85-byte version does not blow the stack. :P

Comment: @MathuSumMut: Easy fix: require compiling with optimizations. Tail call recursion saves the day.

Comment: There's a lot of scope for saving bytes here.  See my answer for packing stuff inside the `for(;;)`, and for shorter functions than `fprintf`.  If you did need to include stdio.h (which you don't), you don't need a space: `#include<stdio.h>`

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 14 bytes

```
For[,1>0,a>>a]
```

Repeatedly writes the string `"a"` to a file named `a` in the current directory, creating it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: would it write the string "a" or the contents of the variable a? And if the latter, what would it do if that variable were not yet defined?

Comment: @MichaelStern It writes the variable `a`, which is undefined, so it just writes `a\n`.

Answer (score 3):

### C, 40 bytes

```
main(){for(;;)write(open("a",1)," ",1);}
```

---

It will quickly run out of file descriptors, though; this can be overcome with:

### <s>45</s>, 43 bytes

```
main(f){for(f=open("a",1);;)write(f,"",1);}
```

Comment: Why doesn't f have a type in the second?

Comment: @cat In C (very K&R style) it defaults to `int`.

Comment: gcc and clang won't compile the 2nd version.  Even GNU C doesn't allow dynamic initialization of a static/global variable (a call to `open()` isn't a compile-time constant).  Also, it will run out of disk space, because there's no lseek.  Maybe try `utime("a","")` in the loop, which will keep updating the `ctime`.  (You still have to `open` to create a file of known name).

Comment: @PeterCordes You're right, thanks for pointing out. Fixed.

Comment: Still doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement of not filling up the disk eventually, but maybe still worth keeping as an answer.  (Unless you have an idea better than my answer's close/reopen(O_TRUNC) in a loop.)  Contrary to my previous comment, updating timestamps only usually doesn't really produce actual disk I/O on Linux.  Like maybe one write per 24 hours with `lazytime`, as I said in my answer.

Comment: You can save two bytes in this fill-the-disk version:  put the `f=open()` in the run-once first statement of the `for` loop (saving a `;`).  (I got that trick from cat's answer).  And, the empty string still has a 0-terminator, so you can take out the space in the string you pass to `write(f,"",1)`.  Again, see my answer.)

Comment: @PeterCordes No, you're supposed to create an infinite I/O: appending to a file would not because it'd eventually stop due to OS failure (OP's specifically said that). You indeed see in the other answers it's just overwriting, in the accepted one foremost.

Comment: Ok, well this answer fails the requirement of running forever, since you keep appending one byte at a time with each `write`.  See my answer for code that doesn't.

Comment: @PeterCordes Why? `1 = O_WRONLY`, which doesn't seek to the end (you'd also need `O_APPEND`).

Comment: `write()` advances the current file position by the number of bytes written.  Leaving off `O_APPEND` doesn't change that, it just changes the *initial* position of the file descriptor.  You could use `pwrite(3,"",1,0)` to keep over-writing byte 0 of the file, but that doesn't produce real disk activity on my Linux system.  Even close/reopen without `O_TRUNC` didn't light up my hard-drive LED.

Comment: mixing standards lol

Answer (score 3):

## C on amd64 Linux, 36 bytes (timestamp only), <s>52</s> 49 bytes (real disk activity)

I hard-code the `open(2)` flags, so this is not portable to other ABIs.  Linux on other platforms likely uses the same `O_TRUNC`, etc., but other POSIX OSes may not.

**+4 bytes** to pass a correct permission arg to make sure the file is created with owner write access, see below.  (This happens to work with gcc 5.2)

## somewhat-portable ANSI C, 38/51 bytes (timestamp only), 52/67 bytes (real disk activity)

Based on @Cat's answer, with a tip from @Jens.

The first number is for implementations where an `int` can hold `FILE *fopen()`'s return value, second number if we can't do that.  On Linux, heap addresses happen to be in the low 32 bits of address space, so it works even without `-m32` or `-mx32`.  (Declaring `void*fopen();` is shorter than `#include <stdio.h>`)

---

**Timestamp metadata I/O only**:

```
main(){for(;;)close(open("a",577));}   // Linux x86-64

//void*fopen();       // compile with -m32 or -mx32 or whatever, so an int holds a pointer.
main(){for(;;)fclose(fopen("a","w"));}
```

---

**Writing a byte, actually hitting the disk** on Linux 4.2.0 + XFS + `lazytime`:

```
main(){for(;write(open("a",577),"",1);close(3));}
```

`write` is the for-loop condition, which is fine since it always returns 1.  `close` is the increment.

```
// semi-portable: storing a FILE* in an int.  Works on many systems
main(f){for(;f=fopen("a","w");fclose(f))fputc(0,f);}                 // 52 bytes

// Should be highly portable, except to systems that require prototypes for all functions.
void*f,*fopen();main(){for(;f=fopen("a","w");fclose(f))fputc(0,f);}   // 67 bytes
```

---

### Explanation of the non-portable version:

The file is created with random garbage permissions.  With `gcc` 5.2, with `-O0` or `-O3`, it happens to include owner write permission, but this is not guaranteed.  `0666` is decimal 438.  **A 3rd arg to `open` would take another 4 bytes**.  We're already hard-coding O_TRUNC and so on, but this could break with a different compiler or libc on the same ABI.

We can't omit the 2nd arg to `open`, because the garbage value happens to include `O_EXCL`, and `O_TRUNC|O_APPEND`, so open fails with `EINVAL`.

---

We don't need to save the return value from `open()`.  We assume it's `3`, because it always will be.  Even if we start with fd 3 open, it will be closed after the first iteration.  Worst-case, `open` keeps opening new fds until 3 is the last available file descriptor.  So, up to the first 65531 `write()` calls could fail with `EBADF`, but will then work normally with every `open` creating fd = 3.

577 = 0x241 = `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` on x86-64 Linux.  Without `O_TRUNC`, the inode mod time and change time aren't updated, so a shorter arg isn't possible.  `O_TRUNC` is still essential for the version that calls `write` to produce actual disk activity, not rewrite in place.

I see some answers that `open("a",1)`.  O_CREAT is required if `a` doesn't already exist.  `O_CREAT` is defined as octal 0100 (64, 0x40) on Linux.

---

No resource leaks, so it can run forever.  `strace` output:

```
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 03777762713526650) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
... repeating
```

or

```
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 01) = 3
write(3, "\0", 1)                       = 1   # This is the terminating 0 byte in the empty string we pass to write(2)
close(3)                                = 0
```

I got the decimal value of the `open` flags for this ABI using `strace -eraw=open` on my C++ version.

On a filesystem with the Linux `lazytime` mount option enabled, a change that only affects inode timestamps will only cause one write per 24 hours.  With that mount option disabled, timestamp updating might be a viable way to wear out your SSD.  (However, several other answers only do metadata I/O).

---

### alternatives:

**shorter non-working**:

`main(){for(;;)close(write(open("a",577),"",3));}` uses `write`'s return value to pass a `3` arg to close.  It saves another byte, but doesn't work with gcc -O0 or -O3 on amd64.  The garbage in the 3rd arg to `open` is different, and doesn't include write permission.  `a` gets created the first time, but future iterations all fail with `-EACCESS`.

**longer, working, with different system calls**:

`main(c){for(open("a",65);pwrite(3,"",1);)sync();}`  rewrites a byte in-place and calls `sync()` to sync all filesystems system-wide.  This keeps the drive light lit up.

We don't care which byte, so we don't pass 4th arg to pwrite.  Yay for sparse files:

```
$ ll -s a
300K -rwx-wx--- 1 peter peter 128T May 15 11:43 a
```

Writing one byte at an offset of ~128TiB led to xfs using 300kiB of space to hold the extent map, I guess.  Don't try this on OS X with HFS+: IIRC, HFS+ doesn't support sparse files, so it will fill the disk.

[XFS is a proper 64bit filesystem, supporting individual files up to 8 exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS).  i.e. 2^63-1, the maximum value `off_t` can hold.

`strace` output:

```
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 03777711166007270) = 3
pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 139989929353760)     = 1
sync()                                  = 0
pwrite(3, "\0", 1, 139989929380071)     = 1
sync()                                  = 0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 46 bytes

```
(do()(#f)(write-to-file'a"f"#:exists'replace))
```

Comment: I was thinking of answering in Racket, but you beat me to it. :P

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you find a shorter answer?

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 73 bytes

```
USING: io.files io.encodings
[ 0 "a" utf8 set-file-contents ] [ t ] while
```

Sets the file contents to the nul byte forever.

Answer (score 1):

## CBM BASIC 7.0, 9 bytes

```
0dS"a":rU
```

This program, when run, repeatedly saves itself to disk.  Here's a more readable version which doesn't use BASIC keyword abbreviations:

```
0 dsave "a" : run
```

Comment: Does it run out of cassette tape though? ;)

Comment: @MathuSumMut that would be `0 SAVE "A" : RUN`

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
while 1:open("a","w").write("b")
```

Note that if run on python 3, this will produce an infinite number of warnings. Also, it will probably run out of fds if run in a non-refcounting implementation.

Comment: Just as a note, a shorter answer exists without the `write` and the `"w"` part of the open command.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM) 15.0, 17 bytes (non-competing)

```
(⊢⊣⊃⎕NPUT⊢)⍣≢'A'1
```

Chrome currently renders U+2262 wrong. The above line should look like `(⊢⊣⊃⎕NPUT⊢)⍣̸≡'A'1`.

This is non-competing because version 15 has not been released yet.

Applies `⍣` the function `(⊢⊣⊃⎕NPUT⊢)` on `'A'1` until the input is changed (i.e. never):

`⊢⊣⊃⎕NPUT⊢` is a function train:

```
┌─┼───┐      
⊢ ⊣ ┌─┼─────┐
    ⊃ ⎕NPUT ⊢
```

The rightmost `⊢` returns `'A'1` unmodified; this (filename, overwrite-flag) will be the right argument to `⎕NPUT'.

'⊃' returns the first element of `'A'1` (`'A'`); this is the data to be written.

Then `⎕NPUT` is run, and reports how many bytes were written (2 or 3 depending on OS); this becomes the right argument to the `⊣`.

The leftmost `⊢` again returns `'A'1` unmodified; this is the left argument to the `⊢`.

`⊣` ignores its right argument and returns the left argument (`'A'1`), this becomes the new value fed to `⍣`.

Since the new value is identical to the old one, the operation is continued (forever).

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 12 bytes

```
SAVE"A
EXEC.
```

Comment: Doesn’t it run out of cassette tape though?

Answer (score 0):

## vim text editor, 10 bytes

```
qa:w<enter>@aq@a
```

8 bytes if you do not could the execution command `@a`

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, 39 bytes

```
while''do io.open('a',"w"):write('')end
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 61 bytes.  (or 66 bytes to actually hit the disk on Linux+XFS+`lazytime`)

Timestamp metadata I/O only:

```
#include <fstream>
int main(){for(;;){std::ofstream a("a");}}
```

The disk I/O is due to `a`'s mod time changing, which will be written to disk occasionally.  (*very* occasionally with the commonly-use `lazytime` mount option.  Also see my C answer.)

---

Write data before closing:

```
#include <fstream>
int main(){for(;;){std::ofstream a("a");a<<4;}}
```

Actually hits the disk: lights up my hard drive light.  (Linux 4.2.0, XFS, `lazytime`)

---

The `ofstream` constructor opens the file, and the destructor closes it again.  There are **no resource leaks**, so this will actually run forever without running out of memory, file handles, or disk space.

`strace` output:

```
open("a", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "4", 1)                        = 1      # not present with first version
close(3)                                = 0
... repeating
```

Answer (score 0):

## C99, 84 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){while(1){FILE*f=fopen("a","w");fputc(9,f);fclose(f);};}
```

If you don't care about buffers, you can do this instead:

---

## C99, 65 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){while(1){fputc(9,fopen("a","w"));};}
```

I don't know if it closes automatically (no file handle), so please comment and I'll edit.

---

Lots of \ts to write (relax, they're not infinite!).

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 36 bytes

```
set f [open a w]
while 1 {puts $f .}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/OLVEIU0hOr8gNU8hUaE8lqs8IzMnVcFQobqgtKRYQSVNQa/2/38A)