# Restricted powers of two

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, restricted-source

## Challenge

Given a number `x`, output the first `x` powers of two, starting with 2¹ (2).

#### Example

```
2   2 4
3   2 4 8
1   2
6   2 4 8 16 32 64
```

You may output numbers separated by non-numerical characters. You may not just output them mashed together like `248163264128`.

## Rules

- In your code, you may only use the number `2`. You may not use any other numbers, either as ASCII characters or numeric literals in any base.

  - You may not use character literals as integers to bypass this rule.
- You may not use your language's built-in exponentiation function, operator, or similar. You must implement the exponent yourself.

  - You may not use bit shifting operators.
  - You may not use operations that are equivalent to bit shifting.
- Standard loopholes are disallowed.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer wins. However, it will not be selected.

Comment: In my opinion this is the worst type of restricted source challenge.  It is really impossible to verify whether or not a particular program contains a number other than 2 objectively.  Each language becomes its own separate argument about what is and is not allowed.  For restricted source challenges you should be able to write a computer program that can verify if a particular program obeys the rules.

Comment: This is a Do X without Y challenge. I reccomend checking out [things to avoid doing in challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8047/40695)

Comment: In my language there is a `«` operator that in docs is "bitshift left" but is programmed as multiply by two. Can I use that?

Comment: "or similar" what does this mean? Anything which performs repeated multiplication? This is a really fuzzy line which will only be tested in code-golf

Comment: @Downgoat "Or similar" applies to "function, operator". For example, a stack operation or modifier.

Comment: @Mendeleev so I have a 2^N operator which isn't an exportation op/func, can I still use that? It's not exponentiation but according to your wording it's OK

Comment: @Downgoat No. [​](http://test.test)

Comment: If I'm using C can I use a char as a number?  It's not a number in any base but it acts like one

Comment: @Mendeleev Probably should specify that

Comment: (This could have really benefitted from some time in the Sandbox ...)

Comment: I'm not even sure what the purpose of disallowing `2` is. Why would you need any other numbers unless you're using an esolangs where numbers are part of the usual syntax in which case you're just disallowing the entire language for no good reason...

Comment: @StewieGriffin Accidentally middle clicked.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork The Sandbox has mostly been a bad experience for me. Almost every time I've psoted there, the challenge has been mostly ignored.

Comment: @Mendeleev likely because it's a boring challenge.  If it's at all interesting, you're sure to get either votes or feedback.  And bad feedback is _not_ being ignored, that's constructive criticism (idk if you've had any of that though).

Comment: @Riker Have not had any feedback

Comment: What do you expect to gain by not allowing anything but `2`? 99% of languages don't need anything else, and the ones that do are mostly number based esolangs.

Comment: I can see loopholes in two of the restrictions without even spending any time to think about it. Predefined variables which by default hold numeric values but which aren't numeric literals bypass the restriction on using numbers; base conversion bypasses the restriction on exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
(`take`iterate(*2)2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mq5FQkpidmpBZklqUWJKqoWWkaaT5PzcxM0/BVqGgKDOvREFFIU3B5L8JAA)

3 bytes longer than the unrestricted:

```hs
f n=map(2^)[1..n]
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 bytes

```
t/O<\*2Hw&
k\i.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@1@i728To2XkUa7GlR2Tqefw/78ZAA)

#### Explanation

This uses the `w&...k` looping technique explained in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116972/8478).

```
t    Decrement the implicit zero on top of the stack to give -1 to initialise
     the product for later.
/    Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal.
i    Read all input as a string.
     Bounce off bottom boundary, move NE.
<    Set the horizontal component of the IP direction to west, i.e. move NW.
     Bounce off top boundary, move SW.
i    Try reading more input. Just pushes an empty string.
     Bounce off bottom boundary, move NW.
/    Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal.
t    Implicitly discard the empty string and convert the actual input to its
     numerical value N. Decrement it to get N-1.
     IP wraps around to the last column.
&w   Repeat the following bit N times.
  H    Take the absolute value of the top of the stack. This is only
       relevant for the first iteration, because we initialised the product
       to -1 instead of 1.
  2*   Double the current product.
  \    Reflect to SW. Switch to Ordinal.
  .    Duplicate the current product (also converts it to a string, but it
       will be converted back by the H).
       Bounce off bottom boundary, move NW.
  O    Output the current product as a string with a trailing linefeed.
       Bounce off top boundary, move SW.
  \    Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal.
k    End of loop.
     IP wraps around to the last column.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](https://cheddar.vihan.org), 26 bytes

```
n->2/2|>n=>n->[n]*n/(*)
```

Takes n as art generated range [1, n], maps (`=>`) It over [n]*n (array of n n times over multiplication)

No TIO link because cheddar on TIO is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
2ṁ×\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2/0cGfj4ekx////NwMA)

#### How it works

```
2ṁ×\  Main link. Argument: n

2ṁ    Mold; reshape [2] as [1, ..., n], generating an array of n 2's.
  ×\  Take the cumulative product.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 44 bytes

```
(([{}]){}<(()())>){({}<((({})){})>()())}{}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hEV1dG6tZXWujoaGpoalpp1mtAeYASU2gsKYdWLi2Ggj//zcFAA)

Explanation:

```
#Push negative(input * 2)
(([{}]){}

  #And push a 2 underneath it
  <(()())>
)

#While True:
{

    #Pop the top of the stack off
    ({}

       #And double the number underneath it
       <((({})){})>

    #Then push the former top of the stack + 2
    ()())

#Endwhile
}

#Pop two elements, implicitly display stack
{}{}
```

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@6@hoamhaWMHRNUa1bXRGpqxQKaGBpCtqQnENna1QJna//9NAQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 23 bytes

```matlab
@(x)cumprod(~(2/2:x)+2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUaGZXJpbUJSfolGnYaRvZFWhqW2k@T8xr1jDUPM/AA)

Returns cumulative product of repeated 2s.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

```
x=>[...Array(x)].map(_=>p+=p,p=x/x)
```

Using no digits at all.

Answer (score 0):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
2.{t2*
```

Explanation:

```
2       push 2
 .{     repeat input times
   t     output
    2*   multiply by two
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 29 bytes

```
->n{b=2;n.times{puts b;b*=2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

```python
n=2
exec"print n;n*=2;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59na8SVWpGarFRQlJlXopBnnadla2StpJWZV1BaoqH5HyKcpgHla/43AQA)

This might be the shortest way to do it, restrictions or no. Compare

```python
lambda n:[2<<i for i in range(n)]
# 33 bytes, ignoring restrictions
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQZxVtZGOTqZCWX6SQqZCZp1CUmJeeqpGnGfu/oCgzr0QhTSMzr6C0RENT878JAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 11 bytes

```
2ri{_p2*}*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@29UlFkdX2CkVatl/f@/BQA)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 80 bytes

```
@set/px=
@set/ap=2/2
@for /l %%i in (%p%,%p%,%x%)do @set/ap+=p&call echo %%p%%
```

Takes input on STDIN, since `%1` would be illegal. Fully illegal version would only be 63 bytes:

```
@set/ap=1
@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @set/ap+=p&call echo %%p%%
```