# Build me a city

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Coders are always trying to flatten arrays into boring 1-dimensional entities and it makes me sad.

Your task is to unflatten an arbitrary string of characters, outputting a lovely city skyscape.

Consider the string: `aaabbbbbccqrrssstttttttPPw`

It looks much better like this:

```
            tt
            tt
  bb        tt
  bb        tt
aabb      sstt
aabbcc  rrssttPP
aabbccqqrrssttPPww
```

(Ok, yes, the letters are duplicated to make it look more city-skyline-ery).

Take an input string, duplicate each subsection of matching characters (not necessarily alphabetic letters) and build me a city!

Shortest code bytes win.

I actually thought I had the requirements nailed, but to answer some questions:

- it must be on the ground
- you can have extra sky if you want (leading blank lines, surrounding blank space) - but not between the buildings
- letters can be reused inside the string (same architecture, different location)
- the letters are assumed to be ASCII, but more flair will be given to those supporting additional encodings (UTF8, etc)

Comment: Can we output the cityscape rotated 90 degrees?

Comment: Will characters ever repeat again i.e. `aaabbbbaa`?

Comment: @Okx have you ever seen a city rotated 90 degrees, that would look very silly! ;)

Comment: @Tom [maybe..?](https://assets.rappler.com/60B869AC9ADD42A087B5B12BD47DD324/img/5F2E1F09D72549649FAAC629BC11B330/doctor_strange_marvel_studios-018.jpg)

Comment: Welcome on the site! For future challenges, I recommend posting them first in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get feedbacks from the community before posting it as a challenge.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126172/58974). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119430/58974).

Comment: Can we have trailing and leading newlines?

Comment: What character can the input consist of?

Comment: @LiefdeWen Trailing newlines are allowed by default, afaik.

Comment: @Okx Actually asking for leading newlines

Comment: Are trailing spaces permitted?

Comment: Can we have trailing newlines or the buildings will float in mid-air?

Comment: I thought someone had taken my sandbox challenge XD

Comment: How do you construct buildings made out of newlines, carriage returns, or tab characters?

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
γ€DζR»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWtczm0LOrT7///ExMQkEEhOLiwqKiouLi6BgICAcgA)

In a version newer than the challenge, `ζ` has been added as a replacement fo `.Bø`

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
γ€D.BøR»
```

Explanation:

```
γ            Convert into a list of consecutive equal elements
 €D          Duplicate each element
   .B        Squarify; pad each element with spaces so that they are the length of the longest element
     ø       Transpose
      R      Reverse (otherwise the city would be upside-down)
       »     Join by newlines
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWtc9JwO7wg6tPv//8TExCQQSE4uLCoqKi4uLoGAgIByAA)

Comment: Interestingly, Jelly has `z⁶` for `.Bø`...but it also has `Œgx'2` for `γ€D` >_>

Comment: `γ.BD)ø˜øR»` was what I had without looking, `€D` is way better; I feel like we're both missing the 1-byte solution to inline duplication though.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Wait, you solved the challenge without even looking at it?

Comment: @Okx Well, it's wise not to look at the answers before since the whole fun of golfing it yourself could be cut off.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It was a joke, and what I mean was that he solved it without looking at the content of the challenge.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZHTWtczm0LOrT7///ExMQkEEhOLiwqKiouLi6BgICAcgA "05AB1E – Try It Online") - for 6 now.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Œgx'2z⁶ṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPQKdaOqR43bHu6cFfn////ExMQkEEhOLiwqKiouLi6BgICAcgA)

Explanation:

```
Œgx'2z⁶ṚY  Main Link
Œg         Group runs of equal elements
  x        Repeat
   '              the lists
    2                       twice without wrapping
     z⁶    Zip (transpose), filling in blanks with spaces
       Ṛ   Reverse the whole thing so it's upside-down
        Y  Join by newlines
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation please milord? I can't understand what's happening here :o

Comment: @Nathan https://pastebin.com/DzaBSjd5

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Nice explanation...

Comment: Just to be sure, is it correct? :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Well, that wasn't entirely the intention for `'`, which was to repeat the lists themselves and not the items inside them, but overall it's good. :)

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't know exactly what "flat" meant. Thanks :) Also do you want to edit it into your answer? :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Yeah I'll edit it in.

Comment: "So that it's upside down"? Missing negative?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Nope, we turn it upside down to bring it to a correct state, since it's already upside-down according to physics laws.

Comment: In what character encoding is U+1E5A LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R WITH DOT BELOW a single byte?

Comment: @DanielH Jelly has a custom encoding.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Oh, I see. I hadn’t heard of Jelly before and I saw a lot about UTF-8 on the GitHub page and missed the alternative of using its custom codepage.

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 23 bytes

```
qe`::*:__:,:e>f{Se[}zN*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzA1wcpKyyo@3krHKtUurTo4Nbq2yk/r///ExMQkEEhOLiwqKi4uLoGAgIByAA)

Explanation:

```
qe`::*:__:,:e>f{Se[}zN* Accepts (multi-line?) input
q                       Take all input
 e`::*                  Split into groups of equal elements
      :_                Duplicate each
        _:,:e>          Push maximal length without popping
              f{Se[}    Left-pad each to that length with space strings (NOT space chars, although not a problem here)
                    z   Zip
                     N* Join with newlines
```

Comment: Wow, a CJam answer >_>

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>155</s> <s>136</s> <s>134</s> 132 bytes

*-19 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun*
*-2 bytes thanks to @officialaimm*
*-1 byte thanks to @Wondercricket*

```python
s=input()+'+'
k=' '*len(s)
a=[]
c=b=''
while s:
 while c in b:b+=c;c,*s=s
 a+=b+k,b+k;b=c
for r in[*zip(*a)][:0:-1]:print(*r,sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7CsMwEAV7nUKdfg4kpJPZO7g3LqTFwcJGVnYVTHJ5xSEDD6Z4THnXZc/31hhSLq@qjVNOiRWUVHabs2YjAoyTQIiglDiWtM2SvZB/Q5myjD46wB47y8BCBgfRrd25PgKKx06SzttoP6loG8w0@qu/3CZfKOWqLXU8lzNuWgshxB@ITyJi5vpnGI4v)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>15</s> <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Includes trailing spaces on each line.

```
ò¦ Õ®m²ÃÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=8qYg1a5tssPU&input=ImFhYWJiYmJiY2NxcnJyc3NzdHR0dHR0dFBQdyI)

```
ò¦ Õ®m²ÃÔ     :Implicit input of string
ò             :Partition by
 ¦            :  Inequality
   Õ          :Transpose
    ®         :Map
     m        :  Map
      ²       :    Duplicate
       Ã      :End map
        Ô     :Reverse
              :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 117 bytes

```python
import re
s=input()
for l in zip(*[x+S*len(s)for x,_ in re.findall(r'((.)\2*)',s)for S in'  '])[::-1]:print''.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDoIwEEDRPafobqaITWRJ4h1IWCIxFSGOqdM6rRG9fJXwt@@HT7p5rnOmR/CSlExFPBKHV0JdzF6UU8TqSwHLftl1pZsYo15hqc4ryWRm4qt1DgUQjT7VpYZqe7r/AUrBoPum2R@GJghxAjB3T4xO5wzW2svaOD5FYoxpq23f8AM)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>412</s> <s>400</s> <s>330</s> <s>324</s> <s>312</s> 319 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to VisualMelon
-12 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen
but +19 bytes because I forgot to include the imports in the byte count.

```java
import java.util.*;x->{Map m=new HashMap(),n;int l=x.length(),i=l,v,y,h=0,d=1;char c,k;for(;i-->0;m.put(c,d=m.get(c)!=null?d+1:1),h=d>h?d:h)c=x.charAt(i);for(y=h;y>0;y--){n=new HashMap(m);for(i=0;i<l;i++)if(n.get(k=x.charAt(i))!=null){v=(int)m.get(k);System.out.print((y>v?"  ":k+""+k)+(i==l-1?"\n":""));n.remove(k);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBcsIgEIbveQqaEzQJo1cpOr314owzHq0HJGgwhKSwiWYyefaUqId2L7DL7vcv/1V0IqsbZa95OemqqR2ga6jRFrSh7yySRniPtkLbIdIWlDsLqRAoD0PU1TpHDu/BaXtBd8KiMWrak9ESeRAQjkdHFYZfTYcjEu7iCRqiGYEA8emerYetaFDFrbqhL@GLkGGSWhb0kOF3apS9QBFKmpu0S/u04Is050smC@GQTEt2rh1mOsvWC1bRpgUsw3tFLyrcyBu3rTGbPFmuliTM5utik68KIgN6JnwC1uSB6HnB@sDos4wM9t8@1bND8wXTH4bpJCH6jO1DovwLesmRoeM4fIA8tygJ2/ceVEXrFmgTvACM@3W3iRGKV2USx0lJkoDnJltu4m8br@KYEGapU1XdqRkwjiObgDo8W3hYHB9@j9MkhDjNIeWPc957eMZud/sF)

Comment: Golfing Java and C# (my department) is great fun! Keep at it! Not tested, but I think you can save a few bytes by rejigging the for loops: you can pre-assign `i=0`, or better, `i=l`, and count down `for(;i-->0;h=d>h?d:h)` (and stuff the `h=` bit in there). The same back-counting will work for the inner loop also. The inner `if` also has no need for the braces `{}`. And always be weary of `<=` or `>=`, you can turn the ternary around with `>` and save a byte.

Comment: Thanks, I could shave another 6 bytes off the code thanks to your tips. Well, I think I'm going to stay with Java Golfing since I actually like it ;).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm afraid you'll have to increase the byte-count to 329 (+19 bytes due to the required `import java.util.*;` for `Map` and `HashMap`, imports are part of the byte-count; and -1 by removing trailing semi-colon, which isn't part of the byte-count).

Comment: Having said that, you can still golf some parts like this: [`import java.util.*;x->{Map m=new HashMap(),n;int l=x.length(),i=l,v,y,h=0,d=1;char c,k;for(;i-->0;m.put(c,d=m.get(c)!=null?d+1:1),h=d>h?d:h)c=x.charAt(i);for(y=h;y>0;y--){n=new HashMap(m);for(i=0;i<l;i++)if(n.get(k=x.charAt(i))!=null){v=(int)m.get(k);System.out.print((y>v?"  ":k+""+k)+(i==l-1?"\n":""));n.remove(k);}}}`](https://tinyurl.com/y9pdsk8o)

Comment: Summary of the changes: `HashMap<>` → `HashMap`; `Map n=` → `,n` and `n=`; `m.put(c,d=m.get(c)!=null?d+1:1);` inside the for-loop to get rid of the brackets; `k=x.charAt(i)` inside the `if(n.get(k)!=null)` to get rid of the semi-colon and for-loop's brackets. Again, welcome and great answer! +1 from me. Also, in case you haven't seen it yet: [Tips for golfing in Java](https://tinyurl.com/yb2z65sp) and [Tips for golfing in <any language>](https://tinyurl.com/y8kzo4vm) might be interesting to read through.

Comment: Thank you for your support and the welcome :). I've applied all the changes and added the import to the byte count. Also, nice tips for golfing in Java, very helpful.

Comment: [293 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZA/b4MwEMV3PoXLZBewyBrXoG5dIkXKmGZwwAEHY6h9JEGIz06dP0N7y8lP737vfGdxEUnXS3Mum0W1fWcBnb1GB1CavrOg0MI5tBHKTIEyIO1JFBKBdDAFl06VyOIdWGUqdCMsmIN@OGpVIAcCfHs4Wj/8Mu0PSNjKETQFdwQCxJdbkk0b0aOWG3lFX8LV/oVJbJjPQ5rfqJamgtpLiut4jGuexiVfsaIWFhVxw06dxUwlSZaympdZnZfrmrS0HwAXfvzu@wSsiJ9qaSW9St64GbTOy2i1XpEHYOQ1Gz1hTBIymX@7tE@H4ilTH5qpKCLqhM0D1fwNeGHJtBsdyJZ2A9De/xswHjPsO3nmNyQPEQrXTRSGUUMij@Y6WeXhtwnXYUgIM9TKtrtIb2XzPLMFqMX30@3Tw@PO87IIIY73Koofa51z8Kzt9voL "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 150 bytes

```
(z=Characters[v=#];f=CharacterCounts[v][#]&/@(d=Union@z);Row[Column/@Map[PadLeft[#,Max@f,""]&,Table[Table[d[[i]]<>d[[i]],f[[i]]],{i,Length@d}],{1}]])&
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 135 bytes

```r
e=rle(sub('(.)','\\1\\1',strsplit(scan(,''),'')[[1]]));write(sapply(sum(e$l|1):1,function(x)ifelse(e$l>=x,e$v,'  ')),'',sum(e$l|1),,'')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw7CsMwEESv4sKwu7AE1CY4Z3Bvu5CFDAJFcbTyJ5C7KxIpMsxUw3sxZ9tFb1G2GQEvBAzjqEqBJUVZvUsoRgdkAKobBjVNRLcjulQwva7@XegH2tZ/FF0VL1swyT0DnuQW68XW696dbNudoWmAqoj/DFdv1lrPNca8YhSR9EvfH/kL)

reads from stdin, writes to stdout (with a trailing newline).

#### Explanation:

- `rle` finds the lengths of the streaks of characters, the heights of each tower.
- the `sub` expression replaces each character with its double (so I didn't have to muck about with setting adjacent indices together)
- `sapply` returns an array (in this case a matrix):

  - `sum(e$l|1)` is the number of distinct characters; we go from top to bottom
  - `ifelse( ... )` is a vectorized `if...else` allowing us to build a matrix of towers and double spaces
  - `write` writes to console, with a few options to format.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
j_.tsC*2]*Mr8
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.tsC%2a2%5D%2aMr8&input=%22aaabbbbbccqrrssstttttttPPw%22&debug=0)

Comment: 49 minutes... way too slow

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 138 bytes

```php
for(;~$s=&$argn;$s=substr($s,$r++%2*$i))for($i=0;$i<strspn($s,$c=$s[0]);$f[$i++][$r]=$c)a&$f[$i]?:$f[$i]=" ";krsort($f);echo join("
",$f);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoIwFET3nII0I2kti8aln4aDkC6QiFQT2vyPW69eEVczee/lJZeuz0uuK4z8WL1yTlGZE2v6QHxzUNqfvG@ysYa0YGtPlzOiMb8O0TtC7HYreT2CyUMGFwxhHhCtDQM4eExmbA4S@ut/vaoVvVgSbxqzofu0pPqZ4qpVpdofKeUL)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
'(.)\1*'XXtvc!P
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X11DTzPGUEs9IqKkLFkxACiQmJiYBALJyYVFRcXFxSUQEBBQrg4A)

#### Explanation

```
'(.)\1*' % Push string to be used as regexp pattern
XX       % Implicit input. Regexp matching. Pushes row cell array of matching substrings
t        % Duplicate
v        % Concatenate vertically
c        % Convert to char. This reads cells in column-major order (down, then across)
         % and produces a 2D char array, right-padding with spaces
!        % Transpose
P        % Flip vertically. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes:

```
Ａ⟦⟦ω⟧⟧λＦθ¿⁼ι§§λ±¹¦⁰⊞§λ±¹ι⊞λ⟦ι⟧ＦλＦ²↑⁺⪫ιω¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xDoIwFEVn@YqG6b2kJOooE4ODDobFCRlqKdCkKdJXxL@vRcLoXe5wb86RvXByECaEgkh3FqpqrmvODOZJOzgGIyY73TI4j5MwBJqzwl9soz6wteHspjrhFRwQOdsjIisn6v8ddCQqQ2o9xbHS9WYzyH59jAinrYfT/RWNTQPXQdvFPkdC@rApYh6CEOK5RMrROSLya8pyDtk7ZGS@) Link is to verbose version of code. I originally tried a simple loop over the input string to print an oblong every time the letter changed, but I switched to this list-building method as it saved 5 bytes. Explanation: The variable `l` contains a nested list of the input letters. Characters that match the current last list elements get pushed onto the last list otherwise a new sublist is created for that character. It then remains to join the letters in each sublist so that they can be printed vertically twice.

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadS](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 15 + 1 = 16 bytes

+1 byte for the `1` flag.

```apl
⊖⍵
(.)\1*
2/⍪⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn@//9R17RHvVu5NPQ0Ywy1uIz0H/WuAvJ9//9PTExMAoHk5MKiouLi4hIICAgo/28IAA)

`⊖⍵` post-process by flipping upside down

`(.)\1*` runs of identical characters

`2/⍪⍵M` duplicate the columnified **M**atch

The `1` flag causes the results to be merged together.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 116 bytes

```ruby
->s{a=s.scan(/(.)(\1*)/).map{|x,y|[x,y.size+1]}.to_h
m=a.values.max
m.times{|i|puts a.map{|k,v|v+i<m ?'  ':k*2}*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtLDoIwFAD3nKK78vMRXBqrV2CPxDwIxAaqyCsI0p69YpjFrGaGsVxcI9zhQisKAqrw6Sc@BP4tDYMkAIX9auZ4MfkmIPmto7SwoF/3h6cEwoTdWNOWzZ4CLVVNq5GmHzUx3Oc2nswUybNiV84YP7Xh0YacW@uanCNi@aeq3sNARHonyz68cD8)

Comment: `puts a.map{...}` can be replaced with `p(a.map{})`

Comment: `p` will output quote characters, so it's not fit here

Comment: oh, wow, thanks. You learn everyday - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1255362/2047418

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>259</s> 231 Bytes

### Golfed Code

```
#define v a[1][i
i,k,l,x,h,w;main(char*s,char**a){for(;v];w+=2*!x,s=v++],h=x>h?x:h)x=(s==v])*(x+1);h++;s=malloc((x=h++*++w+1)+w);memset(s,32,h*w);for(i=k;v];s[x+1]=s[x]=k=v++],x=k==v]?x-w:(h-1)*w+l++*2+3)s[i*w]=10;printf("%s",s);}
```

### Verbose Code

```
//Variable Explanations:
//i - increment through argument string, must beinitialized to 0
//k - increment through argument string, must be initialized to 0
//l - record x coordinate in return value, must be initialized to 0
//x - record the actual character position within the return string
//arrheight - the height of the return string
//arrwidth - the width of the return string
//arr - the return string
//argv - the string containing the arguments
#define v argv[1][i

i,k,l,x,arrheight,arrwidth;

main(char*arr,char**argv){
  for(;v];                                 //For Length of input
    arrwidth+=2*!x,                        //increment width by 2 if this char is not the same as the last
    arr=v++],                              //set arr to current char
    arrheight=x>arrheight?x:arrheight      //see if x is greater than the largest recorded height
  )x=(arr==v])*(x+1);                     //if this character is the same as the last, increment x (using arr to store previous char)
  arrheight++;                             //increment height by one since its 0 indexed
  arr=malloc((x=arrheight++*++arrwidth+1)+arrwidth); //create a flattened array widthxheight and set x to be the bottom left position
  memset(arr,32,arrheight*arrwidth);       //fill array with spaces
  for(i=k;v];                              //For Length of input
    arr[x+1]=arr[x]=k=v++],                //set x and x+1 positions to the current character, store current character in i
    x=k==v]?x-arrwidth:(arrheight-1)*arrwidth+l++*2+3 //if next char is same as current move vertically, else set x to bottom of next column
  )arr[i*arrwidth]=10;                     //Add new lines to string at end of width

  printf("%s",arr);                        //output string

}
```

Compiled with GCC, no special Flags

#### Edit

Saved 28 bytes thanks to adelphus. His change allowed me to create a define. And I made the while loops into for loops to save 2 bytes each by rearranging the loop. I also fixed an issue where the code would break when the last character in input wasn't singleton. The code will fail if there is only one unique letter but should work in all other cases.

Comment: Nice! But the golfed version doesn't seem to work with arbitrary input for some reason. Removing the final "w" from the sample input appears to lose the q's and repeat the string. Sure it's something small...

Comment: also `while (i < strlen(argv[1]))` can be shortened to `while (argv[1][i])` - loop until null character

Comment: @adelphus Interesting, I'll try it out tomorrow when I get a chance. I did not test anything other than the given test case (lazy I know).

Comment: That actually helped a ton, I was able to fix the problem and reduce by almost 30 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `grouping.extras sequences.repeating`, 94 bytes

```
[ [ ] group-by values dup longest length '[ _ 32 pad-head ] map 2 repeat flip [ print ] each ]
```

Modern Factor doesn't require a conversion to string before printing a sequence of code points, so have a screenshot of running the quotation in the listener:

[image]

Here's a TIO link with the extra `>string`:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY07C8JAEIR7f8WQxsoUsVOwFRsJiFUQWS@bB553l92Lj18fT1I4xQwLO/M1ZKKX6Xw6HPcbtOLH0Ls253cUUpCqN4o7i2ML5WFkZ1jRyOd/5cKBKaYaNEoKRe@xXSwyIrr9ZMwgoqpxVlm@sqlChcsMXN0@eJId03A9BljvWtYIy66NHZYVrlgXCFSvOqY6tR4UUGDGorF9SFu7mY2QPKYfJtPhMhmydvoC)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a string as input and outputs to standard output. Assuming `"aaabbbbbccqrrssstttttttPPw"` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `[ ] group-by values` Split into groups of equal elements.

  **Stack:** `{ V{ 97 97 97 } V{ 98 98 98 98 98 } V{ 99 99 } V{ 113 } V{ 114 114 } V{ 115 115 115 } V{ 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 } V{ 80 80 } V{ 119 } }`
- `dup longest length` Keep the 'city' on the stack but also find the length of the longest 'building.'

  **Stack:** `~city~ 7`
- `'[ _ 32 pad-head ] map` Pad the city with whitespace to be a rectangular matrix.

  **Stack:** `{ V{ 32 32 32 32 97 97 97 } V{ 32 32 98 98 98 98 98 } V{ 32 32 32 32 32 99 99 } V{ 32 32 32 32 32 32 113 } V{ 32 32 32 32 32 114 114 } V{ 32 32 32 32 115 115 115 } V{ 116 116 116 116 116 116 116 } V{ 32 32 32 32 32 80 80 } V{ 32 32 32 32 32 32 119 } }`
- `2 repeat` Repeat each row twice.
- `flip` Transpose the matrix.
- `[ print ] each` Print each row to standard output.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
2|.@|:@#[[;.1~1,2~:/\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jWr0HGqsHJSjo631DOsMdYzqrPRjYv9rcnGlJmfkK6QpqCcmJiaBQHJyYVFRcXFxCQQEBJSr/wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 22 bytes

21 bytes of code, +1 for `-l` flag.

```
Ya@`(.)\1*`RV:yWVyZDs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/MtEhQUNPM8ZQKyEozKoyPKwyyqX4////ujn/ExMTk0AgObmwqKi4uLgEAgICygE)

#### Explanation

```
                       a is 1st cmdline arg; s is space (implicit)
 a@`(.)\1*`            Using regex, create list of runs of same character in a
Y                      Yank that into y variable
              yWVy     Weave (interleave) y with itself to duplicate each item
                  ZDs  Zip to transpose, with a default character of space filling gaps
           RV:         Reverse the resulting list (with the compute-and-assign
                        meta-operator : being abused to lower the precedence)
                       Auto-print, one sublist per line (implicit, -l flag)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 144 bytes

```haskell
f s=let x=groupBy(==)s;l=length;m=maximum(map l x)in concatMap(++"\n")$reverse$transpose$concat[[z,z]|z<-(map(\y->y++(replicate(m-(l y))' '))x)]
```

I'm pretty confident I can do better than this, but this is the best I can come up with for the time being.

Comment: Bad news first: you use functions from `Data.List` which is not in scope by default. You have to either add the `import Data.List` to the byte count or specify a Haskell environment which does include it by default (e.g. change the language from `Haskell` to `Haskell (lambdabot)`. -- Some tips: a) use pattern guards to bind variables instead of `let` and/or declare helper functions directly: `l=length;f s|x<-groupBy(==)s,m<-... =concatMap`. b) `map l x` is `l<$>x`, c) `concatMap("++\n"` is `unlines`. d) `groupBy(==)` is just `group`. e) `concat` is `id=<<`. You use `m` only once, so inline it

Comment: ... f) no need for `()` around `l y`, `replicate ... ' '` and `map ... x`. All in all: `import Data.List;l=length;f s|x<-group s=unlines$reverse$transpose$id=<<[[z,z]|z<-map(\y->y++replicate(maximum(l<$>x)-l y)' ')x]`.

Comment: `groupBy(==)`=`group`, altough I'm not sure whether one is in Prelude and the other isn't. `concatMap` can be written `>>=`, and `map` can be infixed as `<$>`, and `concat[[z,z]|z<-…]` might be `(replicate 2)=<<…` or `(\z->[z,z])=<<…`

Comment: You can shave off one more byte from @Bergi's excellent tip: `(\z->[z,z])` is `(:)<*>pure`, i.e. `...transpose$(:)<*>pure=<<map(\y...)x`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 42 bytes

```
[rle toarr[...*chars]map FIX 2*tr rev out]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/P7ooJ1WhJD@xqChaT09PKzkjsag4NjexQMHNM0LBSKukSKEotUwhv7Qk9r@DVRoXl3piYmISCCQnFxYVFRcXl0BAQEC5ukLafwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 107 bytes

```ruby
gets.gsub(/(.)(\1*)/,'\0
'*2).split('
').map{|x|x.ljust($_.size).chars}.transpose.reverse.map{|x|puts x*""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LctNCsIwEEDhfU8hRcgPMlVP0gMUyiSEWqkaZyYatT17VPTbvNWj5B6lDEEYBk5ONxqM7nbWNBvVbStl9wY4TqNoVSkDJ4yvOc8ZpmNi0eseeHwGA/6AxAsI4ZnjhQNQuAX69D/EJLzKtq6XUhDRfXl/JWJm@Wnb@xs)

a full program which assumes there will be no newlines in the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 98 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(.)\1*/g,y=>s=s.replace(/$/mg,_=>y[i]+y[i--]||'  ',i=n),s=`
`.repeat(n=x.length))&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYqxDoIwFAB3v4IQA62WEjeXxzewq5FnUyqmFuxrEBL@vUocvOGWuweOSMp3QyjGY2whTlBN0uvBotKsZJKfD7vSiBkqAvqHbfk04grVfOou@6@K4rIseZLkogPHBUGzadZbY2AOJmm1M@HOeZZRVL2j3mppe8NaliLibUWpl/dEFH7U9TvlPH4A)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 100 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(.)\1*/g,(y,c)=>s=s.replace(/$/mg,_=>y[i--]?c+c:'  ',i=n),s=`
`.repeat(n=x.length))&&s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBDoIwEEDRvacgxECrpcSdMRm8Ans1UielYGrBToNw@hriwrf9/6kmRej7MRTTMbYQZ6hm6fVoFWpWMsmvh11pBFsEcqgI6B@35cuIO1TLpS@K2xn3eMqTJBc9OC4Imk2zvloF5mCWVjsTOs6zjCIOjgarpR0Ma1mqlHqsEN/eE1H4qetPynn8Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 37 bytes

```apl
{⊃,/⍵↑⍨¨-⌈/≢¨⍵}'(.)\1*'⎕S{2/⍪⍵.Match}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zmzpPJR24TqR13NOvqPerc@apv4qHfFoRW6j3o69B91Ljq0AihYq66hpxljqKX@qG9qcLURUN0qoKieb2JJckYtxAwF9cTExCQQSE4uLCoqLi4ugYCAgHJ1AA)

Answer (score 0):

## q/kdb+, 53 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(|)(+)(,/)(max(#:)each c)$(+)2#(,)c:((&)differ x)_x}
```

**Example:**

```
 q){(|)(+)(,/)(max(#:)each c)$(+)2#(,)c:((&)differ x)_x}"BBPPPPxxGGGGKKKKKKKkkkkEEeeEEEeeEEEEEOOO8####xxXXX"
 "        KK                      "
 "        KK                      "
 "        KK          EE          "
 "  PP  GGKKkk        EE    ##    "
 "  PP  GGKKkk    EE  EEOO  ##  XX"
 "BBPPxxGGKKkkEEeeEEeeEEOO  ##xxXX"
 "BBPPxxGGKKkkEEeeEEeeEEOO88##xxXX"
```

**Explanation:**

```
{reverse flip raze (max count each c)$flip 2#enlist c:(where differ x)_x} / ungolfed function
{                                                                       } / lambda function
                                                      (where differ x)    / indices where x differs
                                                                      _   / cut at these points aabbbc -> "aa","bbb","c"
                                                    c:                    / save in variable c
                                             enlist                       / put this list in another list
                                           2#                             / take two from this list (duplicate)
                                      flip                                / rotate columns/rows
                   (max count each c)                                     / find the longest run of characters
                                     $                                    / whitespace pad lists to this length
              raze                                                        / reduce down lists
         flip                                                             / rotate columns/rows
 reverse                                                                  / invert so buildings are on the ground
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 92 + 1 (-p) = 93 bytes

```perl
while(s/(.)\1*//){$a[$_].=($"x($i-length$a[$_])).$1x2for 1..length$&;$i+=2}say while$_=pop@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCsIgFEB/ZcQltPA6B3sKoR8I9l4xbKwmyDSvsEX06xm1zuM5cEIfXZ3zNFjXM5IM@UltpORPMEdoz6gZrGYGVrh@vKVhsZwjqLm6@lgoxH9Z78BudfUi8yh@O2h18GFvcjbGXL503T1GIkoLTTO9fUjWj5TFocZSlVmEDw)