# Create a binary ruler

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a number **n**, generate the first **n** columns of this pattern:

```
                               #
               #               #
       #       #       #       #
   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
################################ ...
```

The height of the column at (1-indexed) **n** is the number of trailing `0` bits in **n**'s binary representation, plus one. As a result, the bottom layer has every column filled in, the second layer every second column, the third layer every fourth column, etc.

### Rules

- You may input and output through any standard method.
- You may assume the input is an integer between 1 and 999, inclusive.
- The output may contain any amount of whitespace, as long as the pattern is intact.
- The pattern must be 1-indexed, and in the same format as shown here.
- You may use any single non-whitespace character in place of `#`, but you may not change the space character.

### Test cases

```
1
#

2
 #
##

3
 # 
###

4
   #
 # #
####

5
   # 
 # # 
#####

7
   #   
 # # # 
#######

32
                               #
               #               #
       #       #       #       #
   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
################################
```

A few larger test cases can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ETHproductions/96417705cfb7c3b851d2fb3ff2829092).

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.**

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119430/58974).

Comment: Now I can measure distance in binary! Oh wait...

Comment: 1. Does the ruler have to be horizontal? 2. Do the markings have to be `#`?

Comment: @JonathanAllan 1. Yes, and 2. No, they can be any single non-space character. I've added this to the rules.

Comment: The sequence at OEIS: [A001511](http://oeis.org/A001511)

Comment: Also [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68978/34543)

Comment: Is it bugging anyone else how many response tallies are character counts, not byte counts?

Comment: @BrianRisk Many of the languages actually use an custom encoding. Jelly's, for example, can be found [here](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
i=n=input()
while i:i-=1;print((' '*~-2**i+'#')*n)[:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2zzYzr6C0REOTqzwjMydVIdMqU9fW0LqgKDOvRENDXUFdq07XSEsrU1tdWV1TK08z2iov9v9/QwMA)

Prints with lots of leading whitespace. Each row `i` counting down from `n` repeats a pattern of `2**i-1` spaces followed by a `#`. This pattern is repeated up to the width of the ruler, which is the input `n`. This is done by multiplying the pattern string by `n` and taking the first `n` characters with `[:n]`.

The pattern can be made by string formatting for an equal length alternative.

```python
i=n=input()
while i:i-=1;print('%%%ds'%2**i%'#'*n)[:n]
```

A cute slicing method is longer.

```python
n=input();s=~-2**n*' '+'#'
exec"s=s[1::2]*2;print s[:n];"*n
```

Comment: Is the ~ is -1 or +1?

Comment: Never mind, it's (-x) - 1

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
n=int(input())
a=1
while a<n:a*=2
while a:print(("%%%dd"%a%4*n)[:n]);a//=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P882M69EIzOvoLREQ1OTK9HWkKs8IzMnVSHRJs8qUcvWCMa1KigCqdRQUlVVTUlRUk1UNdHK04y2yovVtE7U17c1@v/f2AgA)

Comment: Wow, it took me a while to figure out how the rows are generated. Well done.

Comment: `a=2**len(bin(n))` for 72 bytes

Comment: It will hit memory errors quickly, and print a bunch of extra white space (allowed) - but you can do [54 using Python 2](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDkyvR1khLK4@rPCMzJ1Uh0aqgKDOvRENJVVU1JUVJNVHVRCtPM9oqL9Y6Ud8WqM/QHAA).

Answer (score 9):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>17</s>, 16 bytes

```
é#Àñä}Är {ñÎÀlD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///BK5cMNhzceXiJWe7ilSKEayOw73JDj8v//f3MA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: e923 c0f1 e416 7dc4 7220 7bf1 cec0 6c44  .#....}.r {...lD
```

*Thanks to @KritixiLithos for saving one byte!*

This algorithm is *horribly* inefficient, but it should work in theory for any size input.

It works by generating the first *n* iterations of the following pattern:

```
#

 #
##

   #
 # #
####

       #
   #   #
 # # # #
########

               #
       #       #
   #   #   #   #
 # # # # # # # #
################

                               #
               #               #
       #       #       #       #
   #   #   #   #   #   #   #   #
 # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
################################
```

And then chopping off all but the first *n* columns. As such, this will produce a ton of leading whitespace, but the OP said:

> The output may contain any amount of whitespace, as long as the pattern is intact

Explanation:

```
é#                      " Insert an '#'
  Àñ           ñ        " 'N' times:
    ä<C-v>}             "   Duplicate every line blockwise (duplicating horizontally instead of vertically)
           Ä            "   Duplicate the top line. This conveniently puts us on the first non-whitespace character (that is, '#')
            r           "   Replace this character with a space
              {         "   Move to the beginning of the buffer
                Î       " On every line:
                 Àl     "   Move 'N' characters to the right ('l' for right, makes sense, right?)
                   D    "   And delete everything after the cursor
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can remove the `|`.

Comment: @KritixiLithos Aha! In hindsight, it's so obvious! Thanks for the tip. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 bytes

```apl
'# '[1+⊖0⍪∨⍀⊖2⊥⍣¯1⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO9qDQntei/urKCerSh9qOuaQaPelc96ljxqLcByDF61LX0Ue/iQ@sNH/VuftQ3NRak4z9YC5exEQA)

`'# '[`…`] index the string with

`⎕` get input

`⍳` that many **i**ntegers

`2⊥⍣¯1` convert to binary, using as many digits as needed (one number in each *column*)

`⊖` flip upside down

`∨⍀` vertical cumulative OR reduction

`0⍪` concatenate zeros on top

`⊖` flip upside down (i.e. back up again)

`1+` add one (for 1-based indexing)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>61</s> 58 bytes

```
f=(n,c=n,s='')=>c?f(n,c>>1,s+s+' ')+`
`+(s+1).repeat(c):''
```

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @ETHProductions, then 2 more bytes when I saw that any character could be used.*

A recursive solution.

**Test cases:**

```js
f=(n,c=n,s='')=>c?f(n,c>>1,s+s+' ')+`
`+(s+1).repeat(c):''

console.log(f(32));
console.log(f(1));  
console.log(f(5));  
console.log(f(7));
```

**Animation:**

```js
f=(n,c=n,s='')=>c?f(n,c>>1,s+s+' ')+`
`+(s+1).repeat(c):''

for(let i = 1 ; i < 64 ; i++) {
  setTimeout(_=>document.querySelector('pre').textContent=f(i), i*40);
}
```

```html
<pre>
```

Comment: Well done. You can change `c/2|0` to `c>>1` to save a byte.

Comment: Nice, I need to brush up on my bitwise operators.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
Rọ2‘4ẋz⁶ṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//UuG7jTLigJg04bqLeuKBtuG5mln///8zMg)

1 byte saved after the OP added a relaxation that the character doesn't have to be `#`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <strike>20</strike> 17 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy and @ETHproductions*

```
õ_¤q1 o Ä çoÃ·z w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DW@ENLCg0V8hUOtygcXp5/uPnQ9iqF8v//jY0A)

### Explanation:

Input: 5

```
õ_¤q1 o Ä çoÃ·z w
õ           Ã       // Create a range [1...Input] [1,2,3,4,5]
 _                  // Map; At each item:
  ¤                 //   Convert to binary        ["1","10","11","100","101"]
   q1               //   Split on "1"             [["",""],["","0"],["","",""],["","00"],["","0",""]]
      o             //   Get the last item        ["","0","","00",""]
        Ä           //   Add 1                    [["1","01","1","001","1"]]
          ço        //   Fill with "o"            ["o","oo","o","ooo","o"]
             ·      // Join with new-lines        ["o\noo\no\nooo\no"]
              z     // Rotate 90 degrees          ["ooooo\n o o \n o   "]
                w   // Reverse                    ["   o \n o o \nooooo"]
```

Comment: [20 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V+kcTEgbyBsIMQg52HDt3oxIHc=&input=MzI=)

Comment: @Shaggy Actually, you don't even need the `l`

Comment: @ETHproductions: yep, just figured that out. [18 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V+kcTEgbyDEIOdRw7d6MSB3&input=MzI=)

Comment: [17 bytes](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9V+kcTEgbyDEIOdRw7d6IHc=&input=MzI=)

Comment: A cool trick with bitwise operators is to do `n&-n` to capture only the final `1` and all trailing `0`s in `n`. Not sure if this will help, but it's worth a shot...

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 45 bytes

```matlab
@(n)[[sort(cummin(de2bi(g=0:n)'));g|1]+32 '']
```

Try it on [Octave Online!](http://octave-online.net/#cmd=(%40(n)%5B%5Bsort(cummin(de2bi(g%3D0%3An)%27))%3Bg%7C1%5D%2B32%20%27%27%5D)(20))

Instead of `'#'` prints `'!'`.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 139 bytes

```php
for($f=array_fill(0,$l=1+log($a=$argn,2)," ");$n++<$a;)for($h=1+strspn(strrev(decbin($n)),$i=0);$i<$h;)$f[$l-++$i][$n]=3;echo join("
",$f);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCsMgFEXReVcR5A38aCFNhka6kBCKTWO0iIopha7eSkZ3cm52uU737HJ3gSl71OOgqk2Fw2pTivk9rA@B9xJB30RIO4fRp5QDSdYxUohCTDCKzs01dnzKkSNvKduXv7b16SNHJJLwum@Hn@AUwc4IVyHglxlx0aPaVpe6d2qaXZiEJVXrHw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 Bytes

```
j_.tm*Nhx_.Bd1S
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.tm%2aNhx_.Bd1S&input=70&debug=0)

#### explanation

```
j_.tm*Nhx_.Bd1S
    m         SQ   # map over the numbers from 0 to the implicit input (lambda variable: d)
          .Bd      # Convert d to a binary string: (12 -> 1100)
         _         # reverse: (1100 -> 0011)
        x    1     # get the location of the first 1 ( 2 )
     *Nh           # make one more than that " quotation marks (""")
 _.t               # transpose the list of quotation mark strings and reverse it
j                  # join on newline
```

Comment: @JasonS It's a golfing language based on Python! I now linked [pyth's github](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth). I thought the [Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j_.tm%2aNhx_.Bd1S&input=70&debug=0) link to the online Executor would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>84</s> 74 bytes

```
f(i,l,m){putchar(32+3*!(i&m));i<l?f(i+1,l,m):m?putchar(10),f(1,l,m>>1):1;}
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
void f(int counter, int length, int mask) {
    putchar((counter&mask) ? ' ' : '#');
    if(counter<length) {
        f(counter+1, length, mask);
    } else if(mask) {
        putchar('\n');
        f(1, length, mask>>1);
    }
}
```

#### Test with:

```
int main() {
    f(1, 32, 1023);
    putchar('\n');
    f(1, 1, 1023);
    putchar('\n');
    f(1, 999, 1023);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

#### Explanation

Once again, recursion takes less characters in C than iteration, so the two loops are expressed as the two recursional invocations.

Also, C is a great language for playing tricks with boolean expressions, allowing the decision of whether to put a blank or a `#` to be expressed by the expression `32+3*!(i&m)`. A space has the ASCII value of 32, the `#` is ASCII 35, so we get a blank if any of the bits in the mask is set in `i`.

Comment: Do you even need the `int i,l,m`?

Comment: @ZacharyT No, turns out I didn't. Thanks for saving those 10 bytes :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and' '.join(f(n/2))+'\n'+n*'#'or''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCkAwFAbgVznl4hgnMqSUJ8HFpGXi31puPP347r/wPoeHTslOl7m33RBGkMHOxNXpHXKbo9ZKlbyASxScsY/MyfpIIAeaG9HSSie9DNLqdaQQHR6C/FOlDw)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES8), 71 bytes

The [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) function was introduced in ECMAScript 2017!

```
N=>eval(`for(s='',n=1;n<=N;n*=2)s='\\n'+'#'.padStart(n).repeat(N/n)+s`)
```

```js
f=
N=>eval(`for(s='',n=1;n<=N;n*=2)s='\\n'+'#'.padStart(n).repeat(N/n)+s`)

console.log(f(+prompt()))
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

```
N=>eval(`for(s='',n=1;n<=N;n*=2)s='\\n'+(' '.repeat(n-1)+'#').repeat(N/n)+s`)
```

```js
f=
N=>eval(`for(s='',n=1;n<=N;n*=2)s='\\n'+(' '.repeat(n-1)+'#').repeat(N/n)+s`)

console.log(f(+prompt()))
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 69 bytes

```
Rotate[Grid["#"~Table~#&/@(IntegerExponent[2*#,2]&/@Range[#])],Pi/2]&
```

Answer (score 1):

### ([WESRRMICGSE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102566/60951)): 237 bytes

```
IF(ROW()<=FLOOR(LOG(COUNTA(R1C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[1024]C)+1,2),1)+2,LEFT(REPT(REPT(" ",FLOOR(POWER(2,LOG(COUNTA(R1C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[1024]C)+1,2)-ROW()+2),1)-1) &"#",COUNTA(R1C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[1024]C)+1),COUNTA(R1C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[1024]C)+1),"")
```

Alright. 'splaining time.

First off, replace every `COUNTA(R1C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[1024]C)+1` with simply `[i]`, for input. the token counts the number of cells, not including itself, that contain a  formula, and then adds one, to include itself. Since WESRRMICGSE drags a formula according to the input you give it, this token always results in the input.

we have:

```
IF(ROW()<=FLOOR(LOG([i],2),1)+3,LEFT(REPT(REPT(" ",FLOOR(POWER(2,LOG([i],2)-ROW()+2),1)-1) &"#",[i]),[i]),"")
```

This is much more readable.
You're going to see the `FLOOR(LOG([i],2),1)` token a lot, which simply means take the nearest power of 2 which is less than the input (`[i]`) number. eg: `4->4, 5->4, 6->4, 7->4, 8->8 ...etc`. I'll replace that with `GS[[i]]`

```
IF(ROW()<=GS[[i]]+3,LEFT(REPT(REPT(" ",,FLOOR(POWER(2,LOG([i],2)-ROW()+2),1),1)-1) &"#",[i]),[i]),"")
```

better. breaking down the if clause, we're testing if the row is less than or equal to `GS[[i]]+3`, because all rulers' height is equal to the GS[[i]]+1, this  selects the rows which are equal to the height of the ruler. `+1` for 1-indexing rows, and `+1` again for WESRRMICGSE offset.

The `FALSE` result yields an empty cell (""), and a true result yields `LEFT(REPT(REPT(" ",,FLOOR(POWER(2,LOG([i],2)-ROW()+2),1),1)-1) &"#",[i]),[i])`

currently still editing, stay tuned

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```hs
l m=([2..2^m]>>" ")++'#':l m
f n=unlines$take n.l<$>[n,n-1..0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P0ch11Yj2khPzyguN9bOTklBSVNbW11Z3QoowZWmkGdbmpeTmZdarFKSmJ2qkKeXY6NiF52nk6drqKdnEPs/NzEzT8FWoaC0JLikSEFFIU3B2Og/AA) Example usage: `f 10`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>27</s> 23 bytes

```
↶Ｆ…·¹Ｎ«Ｊι⁰#Ｗ¬﹪ι²«Ａ÷ι²ι#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcy9DoIwFAXgGZ6iweU2gURxdDJhwSghxheopcBNSkv652B49irq4nhyznf4yAzXTMbYYtDuLHoH9JD22hCoFZfeYhBXpgYBu5zUavau8dNdGKCUkmeanPw03zRgTrZvl7QGlYNsk63hMaIUBBrt4KI7Lz@z8geTo7U4KKgwYCe@TU5wdf8vS7rEuC9jEWJh5Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 4 bytes by switching to `JumpTo`.

Comment: It's still absolute, just now it's called `JumpTo` (sorry)

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah, the wiki could do with an update. (Or I assume I could do it should you want to give me edit permission...)

Comment: @ASCII-only Huh, I should have remembered that from https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119904 ...

Comment: Do you have a GitHub account?

Comment: @ASCII-only I have two... I can't decide which one is more appropriate...

Comment: @ASCII-only I could save another byte if `\r` worked after a `PivotLeft()`... assuming `\r` does what I'm guessing it does...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'll fix `\r` as soon as I can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60657/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-neil).

Comment: FYI the 21-byte `\r` version is `↶Ｆ…·¹Ｎ«⸿#Ｗ¬﹪ι²«Ａ÷ι²ι#`.

Answer (score 1):

## k, 33 bytes

```
`0:|" #"{(1+!x){~y!x}/:(x>)(2*)\1}
```

This only seems to work in [AW's interpreter](https://kparc.com).

[image: Example of it working in AW's interpreter.]

[The oK version](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%600%3A%7C%22%20%23%22%7B%281%2B%21x%29%7B~y%21x%7D%2F%3A%7Bx%3Ey%7D%5Bx%5D%282%2a%29%5C1%7D32%3B) (which you can try online) seems to have a bug, requiring a slight change to make it work:

```
`0:|" #"{(1+!x){~y!x}/:{x>y}[x](2*)\1}
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 174 bytes

This method has two parameters, an input for the ruler length, and an output which is the ruler as string.

Golfed:

```
void R(int n,out string s){var l=new int[++n];int i,x=n,y=0;for(s="";x-->1;)for(i=0;0==(l[x]=(x>>i++&1)*i);y=y<i?i:y);for(y++;y-->0;s+='\n')for(x=0;++x<n;s+=y<l[x]?'#':' ');}
```

Indented:

```
void R(int n,out string s){                       // Return the result in an out parameter.
    var l=new int[++n];                           // Use a 1-based array.
    int i,x=n,y=0;                                //
    for(s="";x-->1;)                              // For each number x on the ruler
        for(i=0;0==(l[x]=(x>>i++&1)*i);y=y<i?i:y) // ... find lowest set bit of x, counting the maximum value.
            ;                                     //
    for(y++;y-->0;s+='\n')                        // Count down each line.
        for(x=0;++x<n;s+=y<l[x]?'#':' ')          // Output # for numbers that are tall enough.
            ;                                     //
}
```

#### [Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/inhmxA)

Comment: Would converting to a `Func<int, string>` save you some bytes?

Answer (score 1):

## J, 38 bytes

```
3 :'|.|:''#''#~,.(1+|.i.1:)@#:"0>:i.y'
```

Not great. Lmk if the byte count is off -- I'm on my phone.

Comment: Looks like 38 to me, unless the `3` at the beginning is input...

Comment: @ETHproductions thanks, shame switching from a tacit definition didn't save any bytes...

Comment: 28 bytes with ``0|.@|:'#'#"0~1#.2~:/\i.#:@,]``

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
↔T' ↑moR'#→İr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HblBB1hUdtE3Pzg9SVH7VNOrKh6P///8ZGAA)

I saw a ruler sequence builtin(`İr`), so I just went ahead and found a challenge I could cheat on.

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 91 bytes

```java
n->{int i=10,j;String s="";for(;i-->0;s+="\n")for(j=0;j++<n;)s+=j>>i<<i<j?' ':35;return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xboNAEERr/BUrGoMwJxzHiuQD0kVKkcplkuKMAe0ZL@husWRZfDu5CPdX7Wjm7Wi0uqm0H2rS58s8jKcOK6g6ZS18KaTHKnh6lhW7c@vxDFeXREc2SO33LyjT2tiBgXZVYmTsRDNSxdiT@HiK/JO4bmuzgeWthAYKmCktH0gMWGyzjZZLBrYIQ9n0JpKYpmUmbVKEPxTG/5YuMqmTJCcZO1uXJeY55vp9DevDbi9NzaMhsHKag0C6Tce75foq@pHF4Mq5o6gRahi6e7SNYw/x4iV2XuLVS@y9xJt/xzJ1Wk3zHw)

Ungolfed:

```java
n->{
    int i=10,j; // Since we are allowed extra whitespace, set columns always to 10
    String s = "";
    for(;i-->0;s+="\n")      // Every iteration add a newline, i=9..0
        for(j=0;j++<n;)      // j=1..n+1
            s+= j>>i<<i<j    // if j has less than i trailing 0s in binary form
                ?' '         // add a space else
                :35          // # (java handles ternary return types weirdly)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 34 bytes

```
ri{2bW%0+0#)}%_'#f*\:e>f{Se]}zW%N*
```

Meh.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
f(x,l,n){for(l=512;l/=2;)for(n=0;n++<=x;)putchar(n^x+1?n%l?32:35:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9No0InRydPszotv0gjx9bU0Mg6R9/WyFoTxM@zNbDO09a2sa2w1iwoLUnOSASKxVVoG9rnqebYGxtZGZtaGRpoWtf@z03MzNPQrOZSAII0DUMDoCCYDdRVrKGkBOWlaRgbAZm1/wE)

Comment: Suggest `n+~x` instead of `n^x+1`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 60 + 1 (-n) = 61 bytes

```perl
$n=0|1+(log)/log 2;say(($"x(2**$n-1),X)x($_/2**$n))while$n--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lz9agxlBbIyc/XVMfSCgYWRcnVmpoqChVaBhpaank6Rpq6kRoVmioxOuD@Zqa5RmZOalACd3//83M/@UXlGTm5xX/1/U11TMwNPivmwcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ_&n)¤çTÃz3
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=9V8mbimk51TDejM&input=MzI)

```
õ_&n)¤çTÃz3     :Implicit input of integer U
õ               :Range [1,U]
 _              :Map each Z
  &n            :  Bitwise AND with -Z
    )           :  Group that operation
     ¤          :  Result to binary string
      ç         :  Fill with
       T        :    0
        Ã       :End map
         z3     :Rotate 90° clockwise 3 times
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```